# why isn't cookie stored in json?

Tags: json, cookies

I went through some tips about read cookies with Regex. Then I found a jQuery plugin to handle that like json. But way isn't cookies stored in json? Isn't json more convient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cookie header itself is a "normal" HTTP header, and follows the usual conventions there, which were established before JSON became popular.

The value of the cookie is completely up to your application, you could use JSON there.